# Binding MVVM XamarinForms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have a class where I declare my 'Entry' and put Binding in its Text , I want the bindingContext to be stored in another class that I have.
But something is going wrong, I do not receive the information in the second class
I'm trying to do it like  below

> BindingContext = new TelaDados();

```
        Label lblNome = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Digite seu Nome:"
        };
        Entry enNome = new Entry() { }
        enNome.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty,"Nome");

        private void GoPaginaDados()
        {
             BindingContext = new TelaDados();  ////<---- HERE
             DisplayAlert("ok", enNome.Text, "Ok");
             Navigation.PushAsync(new TelaDados());
        }
```

here below I try to get the information of the first class

> lblNome.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Nome");

the second class would be like this

```
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Idade { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }

    public TelaDados()
    {
        Label lblNome = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Blue,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Green
        };
        lblNome.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Nome");
        BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: TelaDados should implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: is `TelaDados` a Page?  You are not using MVVM if the page is its own BindingContext, and especially for one page to be the BindingContext of another page.  The entire point of MVVM is to provide **separation** between the View and the Model.  You are also creating multiple instances of `TelaDados`, so changes made to one instance will have no impact on the others.

Comment: *"I want the bindingContext to be stored in another class that I have."* - why? What is your goal? Step back from these details, and give a careful explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, as it would look from a user's perspective.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do with `lblNome`, the code you have now makes no sense. I recommend using Xamarin Forms the way it is designed to be used: write XAML to describe UI elements. Learn about MVVM from some existing example that works. Instead of using `SetBinding` in c#, use the equivalant XAML: `SomeAttribute={Binding SomeProperty}`. Follow tutorials, until you understand them. Download samples, and make small changes, until you understand what is going on. The code you have suggests fundamental misunderstanding. **Start over.**